# how to check the snapshot is exist in firestore query

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

hi iam following the tutorial for react native appliction when there is a  no snapshot a page will open and the user fill the details and it will be updated in the firestore.
it has "users" collection and "docid" which contains user mail id profile .
code for above :
`useLayoutEffect(() => { onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", user.uid), (snapshot) => { if (!snapshot.exists()) { navigation.navigate("Modal"); } }); }, []);`

i want to simulate this code ,but im getting error
what i did

myfirebase schema is "users""docid" and it has another collection "userdetails""doc.id"
please help me

Comment: what i did is
 `const getUserDetails = async () => {
      if (uid) {
        const userDetailsSnapshot = await getDocs(
          collection(firestore, "users", uid, "userdetails")
        );
        userDetailsSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          setDocId(doc.id);
        });
      }
    };

    getUserDetails();`

Comment: Which version of the JS SDK are you using? Also when you say "I'm getting error", which exact error?